# Side-by-side links with increased size on hover without upsetting other links

Tags: html, css

I have a goal that I'm trying to accomplish with HTML and CSS only: With an inline list of links that grow in size upon hover and **change fonts** (this has caused odd issues before),

A) Hovering one link shouldn't upset other links.

B) Keep it dynamic to avoid tailoring the CSS to each new link.

C) If margin: 0 20px 0 20px, that should be from the ends of the text -- This looks much cleaner, as it makes the spacing constant between links (see example for what should *not* be done). Fixed width containers usually violate this.

D) Upon hover, the text should stay vertically and horizontally centered in place.

E) Please try to keep it HTML and CSS only. If it includes JS or JQ, it would be more difficult to implement to to my lack of knowledge about the languages and the fact that the JSFiddle is just a stripped down example instead of my actual page.

My best right now fits the first two and last criteria without meeting the third, and it uses tables (I *know*):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lftpqha/6/)

Or code:

```
<table><tr>
    <td><div>ONE</div></td>
    <td><div>TWO</div></td>
    <td><div>THREE</div></td>
    <td><div>FOUR</div></td>
    <td><div>FIVE</div></td>
</tr></table>
```

And...

```
div:hover {
    font-size: 130%;
    font-family: comic sans ms;
}
div {
    width: 10px;
    margin: 0 30px 0 30px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

The issue is that the margin is being measured from the *div*, not the *text*, making it so I'd have to tailor the margin to each link. Additionally, hovering will make it seem like the font / link moves down and to the right, violating guideline D.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lftpqha/7/) Works dynamically as long as the text isn't too long, but hovering upsets other links. It also violates D.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking more for something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/1Lftpqha/2/)?

Comment: This works, yes, but I was actually trying to change the font, which causes issues. I should have been more specific and will update my question ASAP.

Comment: How's this? http://jsfiddle.net/1Lftpqha/3/ (based on Fiddle by @PieCrust ), or http://jsfiddle.net/1Lftpqha/4/

Comment: See guidline C. While this does work, if there is a drastic difference in text size, it does not. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lftpqha/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical alignment for inline text is handled easily with the `line-height` property. Make sure that for both the normal and large font-sizes the line height is the same. Eg. for normal text I used `line-height: 1.5em`, for the large text I used `font-size: 130%; line-height: 1.15385em;`. 1.30 × 1.15385 = 1.50

The main issue I see is that when hovering the browser needs the text in the original size for the layout, but it also needs the text in bigger size for display. One solution I see is duplicating the link text and show only one version depending on hover state:

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><span>link 1</span><span>link 1</span></a>
<li><a href="#"><span>link 2, with some long text</span><span>link 2, with some long text</span></a>
<li><a href="#"><span>link 3</span><span>link 3</span></a>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul, li {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
li { list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; line-height: 1.5em; }

li { border: 1px dotted red; position: relative; }
li a span:first-child { padding: 0 30px; }
li a span:last-child { position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 0; font-size: 130%; line-height: 1.15385em; text-align: center; visibility: hidden; }
li:hover a span:first-child { visibility: hidden; }
li:hover a span:last-child { visibility: visible; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g16Ldusx/2/

Instead of duplicating the link text in HTML, I would probably duplicate it using some javacript.

If you don't want the duplication and really don't want javascript, you can use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements instead, and put the link text in a HTML5 data attribute. Not sure how good the browser support for this one is though.

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" data-text="link 1"></a>
<li><a href="#" data-text="link 2, with some long text"></a>
<li><a href="#" data-text="link 3"></a>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul, li {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
li { list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; line-height: 1.5em; }

li { border: 1px dotted red; position: relative; }
li a:after { content: attr(data-text); padding: 0 30px; }
li:hover a:after { visibility: hidden; }
li:hover a:before { content: attr(data-text); position: absolute; width: 100%; font-size: 130%; line-height: 1.15385em; text-align: center; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kyad4tfh/

Also, note that requirements A and C may conflict with each other. The margin between elements needs to be big enough to accomodate for the increased width of the text.

Comment: This seems well thought out and I will try it out asap. As for the least bit, you could use padding instead to avoid this, no?

Comment: Also, I shoiuilkd point out that in B I mean centered over the area where th e smaller text was, in ordeorder avoid it looking like the text moved positions. Having it centered in the container would probably be a clean way to do this, as I think you were implying.

Comment: Instead of having padding, you can make the second `span` a bit bigger than the first, see http://jsfiddle.net/g16Ldusx/3/. For long text and big size differences, the big text may overlap with the links on the left and right.

Comment: Don't know if this code was better than the others, but I got it to work for my needs. Thank you!!

Comment: Can you explain how the positioning works? I need to know in order to make the page scalable and dynamic, but I don't quite get it. I see very little spacing CSS, but removing position:relative, well, breaks the thing. How can I edit the margin / padding from the top?

Comment: You can add padding and margin to the surrounding `<ul>` element, as you would with any other element. You need `position: relative` on the `<li>` elements, it's a precondition for `position: absolute` to work. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)